# после введения границы переменной появляются одни нули

Tags: c

Задание: написать программу с двомерным массивом, занести в массив значение функции 
f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1 и вывести его на экран. При этом значение х и у задается в границах( к примеру от -10 до 0).

Основная проблема в том что если поставить границу от 0 до 9, то на экране начинают бесконечно выводится нули, не знаю как исправить.

Вот мой код

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    float i, j;
    float a[300][300];
    int k = 0;
    int s = 0;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    float Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax;
    float shagX, shagY;
    float Fmax;
    float F;
    printf("F[x,y] = x^2 + y^2 - 1; \n");
    printf("Введите границы Х и У через пробел\n");
    printf("Пример: 0 10 0 10\n");

    scanf_s("%f", &Xmin);
    scanf_s("%f", &Xmax);
    scanf_s("%f", &Ymin);
    scanf_s("%f", &Ymax);

    shagX = (abs(Xmax) + abs(Xmin)) / 10;
    shagY = (abs(Ymax) + abs(Ymin)) / 10;

    Fmax = Xmax*Xmax + Ymax*Ymax - 1;


    printf("  X");

    for (i = Xmin; i <= Xmax; i += shagX) {
        if (Fmax <0) { printf("   "); }
        if (Fmax > 9 && i<11 && i>-1) { printf(" "); }
        if (Fmax > 99) { printf(" "); }
        if (Fmax > 999) { printf(" "); }
        printf(" %.2f", i);
    }
    printf("\ny");

    for (j = Ymin; j <= Ymax; j += shagY)
    {
        y++;
        printf("\n");
        printf("%.2f    ", j);
        if (j>0 && j<10) { printf(" "); }
        for (i = Xmin; i <= Xmax; i += shagX)
        {
            x++;

            F = i*i + j*j - 1;
            printf("%.2f ", i*i + j*j - 1);
            if (a[x][y] < 10) { printf("  "); }
            if (a[x][y] < 100 && a[x][y] > 10) { printf(" "); }

        }

    }



    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, описанную вами беду исправить просто - `abs` функция в C целочисленная, вам `fabs` нужен...

```
shagX = (fabs(Xmax) + fabs(Xmin)) / 10;
shagY = (fabs(Ymax) + fabs(Ymin)) / 10;
```

Но вот что-то мне сама ваша программа - то же вычисление шага - кажется несколько странным...

Словом, раз уж надо именно с массивом, то я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    double a[11][12];

    double  Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax;
    printf("F[x,y] = x^2 + y^2 - 1; \n");
    printf("Введите границы Х и У через пробел\n");
    printf("Пример: 0 10 0 10\n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &Xmin);
    scanf_s("%lf", &Xmax);
    scanf_s("%lf", &Ymin);
    scanf_s("%lf", &Ymax);

    double shagX = (Xmax - Xmin) / 10;
    double shagY = (Ymax - Ymin) / 10;

    printf(" X/Y   ");
    for (double x = Xmin; x < Xmax+shagX/2; x += shagX)
    {
        printf("%6.2lf ",x);
    }
    puts("");

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        double y = Ymin + i*shagY;
        a[i][0] = y;
        for(int j = 0; j <= 10; ++j)
        {
            double x  = Xmin + j*shagX;
            a[i][j+1] = x*x+y*y-1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 11; ++j)
            printf("%6.2lf ",a[i][j]);
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Хотя без массива, понятно, проще :)